# Infer an schema to existing DataFrame pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have data in the spark dataframe already. I want to infer schema on the dataframe and not on the file.

df has already data that I needed. (I cant read the data from file and infer schema because I have got all the necessary columns after filters and joins from multiple input files into a dataframe df). Before writing the df to parquet file I want to infer schema on it. How can I do that?

I have StructType schema defined in parameter called 'schema'

I tried to infer the schema on df using rdd -

```
test_df=spark.createDataFrame(data=df.rdd,schema=schema)
```

when I execute test_df.show(1) I get error :

```
>>> test_df.show(1)

23/08/24 22:46:10 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 10)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/apache-spark/3.4.0/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 830, in main
    process()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/apache-spark/3.4.0/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 822, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(out_iter, outfile)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/apache-spark/3.4.0/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 274, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

How can I infer schema on dataframe - df in pyspark?

Comment: Could share share more about the error message and code? I tested your case and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a dataframe, so there's no need to create a dataframe again. If you want to look at the schema of your dataframe, you can use

```
df.schema
```

Comment: how do I enforce the new schema on the existing dataframe? data is not in a variable but its in a dataframe

Comment: Ah now I understand. You'll need to transform the columns of the dataframe one by one. For example: withColumn(col, f.col(col).cast(type). You can do this in a loop by looping over the columns in your structtype.

Comment: I am able to do the type like StringType, IntegerType but how do you do the Null = True or False ?

Comment: I believe you can do df.schema["colum name"].nullable = True